# Scala syntax for anonymous object

Tags: java, scala, oop, anonymous-class

I'm trying to find the Scala syntax corresponding to this java code. Assume A is a class a has got a method sayHi.

`new A().sayHi()` would be perfectly compilable as per valid java syntax. On the other hand, when I tried `new A.sayHi()` it does not compile in Scala. What syntax do we have in Scala for this?

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, one could use one of the following:

```
new A().sayHi()
(new A).sayHi()
```

Without parentheses and when preceded by `new`, `A.sayHi` would be interpreted as a type and `new A.sayHi()` would then be an instantiation of the class type `A.sayHi`. If `A.sayHi` is not a class type that would result in a compile error.

Take a look:

```
scala> class A { def sayHi() = "hi" }; object A { type sayHi = String }
defined class A
defined object A

scala> new A().sayHi()
res0: String = hi

scala> new A.sayHi()  // same as `new String()`
res1: String = ""

scala> (new A).sayHi()
res2: String = hi
```